# Increasing the space for x axis labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting, but find that I need to increase the area underneath chart such that I can plot the labels vertically but in a font size that is not so tiny. At the moment, I have:

```
plt.figure(count_fig) fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, ratio_lst, width, color='r', linewidth=1, alpha=0.8, log=1) 
ax.set_ylabel('') 
ax.set_title('') 
ax.set_xticks(ind_width) 
ax.set_xticklabels(labels_lst, rotation='vertical', fontsize=6)
```

At the moment it works, but the labels often run-off the edge of the plot.

Comment: Can you just do `fig.tight_layout()` to fix it? Or it doesn't work for rotated ticklabels?

Comment: @inclement Nope - it doesn't.

Comment: Just tried ```fig.tight_layout()``` and it looks like it now works for rotated ticklabels!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) will do it. You can play with the `bottom` keyword to get a good placement of the bottom of the plot.

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
```